# Setting active class on data driven navigation

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I've created some data in my `_data` folder that is working properly. I am using it create a navigation system.

In my data file `elements.yml`:

```
- name: design-elements

- name: ui-components

- name: helper-classes
```

For my simple navigation I add an `active` class if the `page.url == {{data.name}}`. I am writing that like this:

`{% for element in site.data.elements %}
<li {% if page.url == '/{{ element.name }}.html' %} class="active"{% endif %}>`

It *never* resolves to true, even when my page nav is the same as the `{{element.name}}`.

If I write it explicity like this it works:

`<li {% if page.url == '/design-elements.html' %} class="active"{% endif %}>`

I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{}}` inside `{%%}` doesn't work.

So this:

```
<li {% if page.url == '/{{ element.name }}.html' %} class="active"{% endif %}>
```

should be rewritten without them. In this case I use the `capture` tag but it an also be done assigning the resulting url to a new string and then comparing it:

```
{% capture new_url %}/{{element.name}}.html{% endcapture %}
<li {% if page.url == new_url %} class="active"{% endif %}>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but now I am curious how it could be done using `assign`, like you've mentioned.

Comment: @justinw using append, something like: {% assign newurl = '/' | append:element.name|append:'.html' %}